# How to Stop Tkinter TImer Thread?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a simple count-up timer in tkinter. The timer starts and counts up but I can't figure out how to stop it. I am trying to use threading.event but I'm missing something and I just can't get the code right.

Running the code below gives me "attributeError: 'MainFrame' object has no attribute 'x'".

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.9
   
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from threading import Thread
from threading import Event
import time

class Timer(Thread):
    def __init__(self, count):
        super().__init__()

        self.stop_threads = Event()
        self.entry1 = None
        self.count = count

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.stop_threads.is_set():
                break;
            else:
                mins, secs = divmod(self.count, 60)
                timeformat = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
                #print(timeformat, end='\r')
            
                self.entry1 = timeformat
                time.sleep(1)
                self.count += 1 

    def stop_threads(self):
        self.stop_threads.set()

class MainFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
     
        ### TOP BUTTON ROW
        self.frame1=ttk.Frame(self, padding = (0, 50, 0, 30), ) ## LH padding, TOP padding, RH padding, BOTTOM padding
        self.frame1.pack(fill="x", ipadx=0, ipady=0, padx=0, pady=0, expand=False)

        ### TOP TEXT BOX
        self.frame2=ttk.Frame(self, padding = (0, 0, 0, 0), ) ## LH padding, TOP padding, RH padding, BOTTOM padding
        self.frame2.pack(fill="x", ipadx=0, ipady=0, padx=0, pady=0, expand=False)

        ### MID TEXT BOX
        self.frame3=ttk.Frame(self, padding = (40, 20, 40, 0))
        self.frame3.pack(fill="x", ipadx=0, ipady=0, padx=0, pady=0, expand=False)

        # show the frame on the container
        self.pack()

        ### START BUTTON
        self.button1=tk.Button(self.frame1, text='START')
        self.button1['command'] = self.delay
        self.button1.pack(expand=True, padx=0, pady=0, ipadx=0, ipady=0, side="left")

        ### STOP BUTTON
        self.button2=tk.Button(self.frame1, text='STOP')
        self.button2['command'] = self.stop
        self.button2.pack(expand=True, padx=0, pady=0, ipadx=0, ipady=0, side="right")

        ### TIMER DISPLAY LABEL
        self.entry1_label=tk.Label(self.frame2 , text='TIMER', bg="white", fg="blue")
        self.entry1_label.pack(padx=10, pady=0, ipadx=0, ipady=0, expand=False, side="left")

        ### TIMER DISPLAY
        self.entry1_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.entry1=tk.Entry(self.frame2, textvariable="entry6_var", width=10, justify="center")
        self.entry1.pack(padx=0, pady=0, ipadx=0, ipady=4, expand=False, side="left")

        ### MSG DISPLAY
        self.text1 = tk.Text(self.frame3, height=1)
        self.text1.pack(expand=False, padx=0, pady=0, ipadx=0, ipady=0, side="left")        

    def delay(self):
        event = Event()
        self.button1['state'] = tk.DISABLED
        timer_thread=Timer(0)
        timer_thread.start()
        self.monitor(timer_thread)  
 
    def stop(self):
        x = Timer(0)
        x.stop_threads()
        self.text1.insert("end", "stopping")

    def monitor(self,thread):
        if thread.is_alive():
            self.entry1.delete('0', tk.END)
            self.entry1.insert("end", thread.entry1)
            #check the thread every 100ms
            self.after(100,lambda:self.monitor(thread))
        else:
            self.text1.insert("end", "thread is stopped")
            self.button1['state']=tk.NORMAL

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  

        # configure the root window
        self.geometry("600x300")
        self.option_add('*Font', 'Helvetica 9') ## drop down menu font & size / https://coderslegacy.com/python/problem-solving/change-font-in-tkinter/
        self.configure(bg="white") ## bottom background colour
        self.resizable(False, False)

        self.title("TEST TIMER")

        ### frame style 
        f = ttk.Style()
        f.configure('TFrame', background='white') ## background colour

    #def exit(self):
        #self.destroy() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    frame = MainFrame(app)
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
def stop_threads(self):
    self.stop_threads.set()
```

from `Timer` and try `x.stop_threads.set()` instead of `x.stop_threads()`

Part of the issue is that your `Timer.__init__()` says `self.stop_threads = Event()` but `def stop_threads(self)` is overriding that because it has the same name. Ultimately, since you're instantiating the `Event` class with `self.stop_threads`, you don't need the method anyway.

You might run into some trouble, however, because both your `MainFrame.delay` and `MainFrame.stop` methods are instantiating `Timer`, and those timers will have separate stop `Event`s.

You can also fix up the `run` method a bit:

```
def run(self):
    while not self.stop_threads.is_set():
        mins, secs = divmod(self.count, 60)
        timeformat = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        # print(timeformat, end='\r')
        self.entry1 = timeformat
        time.sleep(1)
        self.count += 1
```

All that aside, I'd be careful using `Thread` and `sleep` alongside tkinter. If all you want is a countdown timer, you're better off using `tkinter.after` since it won't cause your app to hang.

If you want to use `after`, you can get remove threading altogether. Here's a rough example:

```
"""Count down from a given number of seconds"""
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ...  # code removed for brevity
        self.time = 120  # time in sec; grab this from a user input
        self.btn_start = ttk.Button(self, text='Start Timer', command=self.timer)
        self.btn_start.pack()

    def timer(self):
        if self.time:  # if there is time remaining...
            # I'm updating the button's text, but you don't have to
            self.btn_start.configure(text=self.time)
          
            # do whatever else you want here; update a label,
            # play a sound, etc.

            # wait 1 sec, call this function again
            self.after_id = self.after(1000, self.timer)
            self.time -= 1  # decrement time remaining
        else:
            self.after_cancel(self.after_id)  # stop the loop
            self.btn_start.configure(text='Start Timer')  # reset btn txt
```

Comment: Happy to help! Have fun

Comment: You advised using tkinter.after rather than time.sleep(), how would I incorporate self.after in the the Timer class?

Comment: I've added a rough example to the answer :) hope that helps some